# VueUse onClickOutside does not work with right click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vueuse, vuejs3-composition-api

I am currently trying to use [onClickOutside](https://vueuse.org/core/onClickOutside/) but it only works when i click outside with the left mouse button.
I need to get this working for the right mouse button too.

Any solution for this? Maybe i missed some option for the function.

Comment: What is your use-case for catching right mouse button?

Comment: A popover is open which i need to close on outer click

Comment: Yea, but it is not classic habit. Right-button clicks are usually ignored in similar cases cause they are not treated like user want to manipulate with your client ui. It is more about manipulating with text or browser itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VueUse does not work here, because no click event is raised. Instead the contextmenu event will be raised here.

Try something like this:

```
import type { Ref } from 'vue'

export const useClickOutside = (target: Ref<HTMLElement>, handler: () => void) => {
  const { isOutside } = useMouseInElement(target)

  const onClick = () => {
    if (isOutside.value) {
      handler()
    }
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', onClick)
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', onClick)
  })

  onUnmounted(() => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', onClick)
    document.removeEventListener('contextmenu', onClick)
  })
}
```